# Multiple threadpools integration

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

In my main flow I have a thread pool ExecutorService, i fill it with a "known" number of Callables, that I invokeAll().

Also there is another ExecutorService object called "globalPool" (my assamption that ExecutorService is thread-safe and I can add tasks to it from different threads ).

Now, each of above Callables spawns new tasks and put them (submit) to  this shared "globalPool".

The problem is that I can't know (can't block) when all tasks are completed and if there are no more incoming tasks.

Please assist.

Code snippet:

```
public class Worker implements Callable {

        private ExecutorService sharedPool;

        public Worker (ExecutorService pool){
          this.sharedPool = pool;
        }




    public boolean call() {
        for (int i = 0; i<100; i++){
           if(i % 10 == 0){
              sharedPool.submit(new Runnable() {                            
                            public void run() {
                               heavyTaskHere();
                            }
                        }   
           }

        }

    }

}


Main flow:

ExecutorService sharedPool = new Executors.newFixedThreadPool(X);
List<Callable<Boolean>> mainthareadPool=  new ArrayList<Callable<Boolean>>();
ExecutorService executor =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(N);


for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
  Wroker w = new Worker (sharedPool);
    mainthareadPool.add(w);
}


executor.invokeAll(mainthareadPool);
```

As I see it The Callables will end **before** their Runable will end.

Comment: If you don't know if there are still tasks to come, how can you even know what "all" **is**?

Comment: @Fildor, each callable spawns new tasks  according to some logic.

Comment: Give us some code please. Imagine you *could* wait for "all" tasks to complete. How would you know that there will be no more tasks created that you have to wait for? I think if you can answer this, you will have made a giant step forward.

Comment: I've added code snippet

Answer (score 0):

If you invokeAll your Callables you get back a List of Futures corresponding to your Callables . With that Futures you can simply see if the Callables has completed by yourFutureList.get(futureOfInterestIndex).isDone()

Comment: but when callable executes its threads it doesn't wait for them to complete and ends so the main flow will end as well